# Is it possible to loose data in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an android app that is storing very important data in local sqlite database. Is there some possibility that data will be lost? I mean beside uninstalling the app or clearing its data

Comment: Data corruption due to hardware/firmware/software failure/malicious intent is certainly a risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: there's no 100% safe storage. In practice the actual answer is no.

Like with all storage, there are risks (ordered from more likely to less likely):

1. Malicious users exploit a vulnerability on the system to mess with your data.
2. Physical support damage, by either external factors (e.g. radiation, strong electromagnetic fields) or by physical wearing (entropy will eventually win)
3. Filesystem corruption (e.g. bugs in the filesystem driver)

Comment: What does `TLDR;` mean?

Comment: Too Long Did not Read

Answer (score -1):

The only where the data is lost: 
1. User clears the appData
2. User Reset's the phone.
So you can store the db file in an external storage with encryption. So the db remains even after the user clears the app data.
The best way to protect the data is to use GDrive integration to backup the db file. So there's always a backup available in the cloud.

Comment: First, user has to authorize you to store his data. Second, cloud backup can also be lost if provider closes its services with or without previous warning (see MegaUpload).